# CNAME file not being copied to root output when publishing Pelican blog

Tags: python, github, pelican

I am following [Tip #2](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/tips.html#extra-tips) from the Pelican documentation to utilize a custom domain on GitHub pages. For this to work correctly, the `CNAME` file needs to be at the root of my site.

From the doc:

> To use a custom domain with GitHub Pages, you need to put the domain of your site inside a `CNAME` file at the root of your site. To do this, create the `content/extra/` directory and add a `CNAME` file to it. Then use the `STATIC_PATHS` setting to tell Pelican to copy this file to your output directory. For example:
>
> ```
> STATIC_PATHS = ['images', 'extra/CNAME']
> EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {'extra/CNAME': {'path': 'CNAME'},}
> ```

I have done this. My `pelicanconf.py` has the following two settings:

```
STATIC_PATHS = ['images', 'extra/CNAME']
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {'extra/CNAME': {'path': 'CNAME'},}
```

I have created my `CNAME` file and placed it in `content/extra/CNAME`, as described in the documentation.

I publish the application like this:

```
pelican content --output output --settings pelicanconf.py
```

This generates my site in the `output` directory. The pages are all set up correctly. However, `CNAME` is not at the root. Instead it is at the `extra/CNAME` location.

I receive no errors or warnings when publishing. If I publish with the `--debug` parameter, this line appears in the output:

```
-> Copying H:\mysite\content\extra\CNAME to extra/CNAME
```

This clearly shows that it's copying it to `extra` instead of the root. According to the documentation, I've set my `STATIC_PATHS` and `EXTRA_PATH_METADATA` correctly to copy this to the root. How do I change my settings so that `CNAME` is copied to the correct location instead of the `extra` directory?

Comment: the file should be in `content/extra/CNAME`, is that what you mean by "The file `extra/CNAME` exists and is populated"?

Comment: It is. The docs assume the `content` is the root of the static paths

Comment: exact. I have the same configuration and it is working fine on Linux. Could this be a Windows related problem?

Comment: That'd be unfortunate, but it's possible. I don't have a Linux box somewhere I can test right now to confirm/deny that hypothesis though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[maggick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509157/cname-file-not-being-copied-to-root-output-when-publishing-pelican-blog#comment49094182_30509157) was correct in his assessment in the comments.

> Could this be a Windows related problem?

There is one tiny mention in the [basic settings overview](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/settings.html#basic-settings)

> Extra metadata dictionaries keyed by relative path. **Relative paths require correct OS-specific directory separators (i.e. / in UNIX and \ in Windows) unlike some other Pelican file settings.** See Path metadata.

*(emphasis is mine)*

This tidbit of information isn't mentioned in the [Path metadata](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/settings.html#path-metadata) documentation or in the [tips](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/tips.html#extra-tips), both of which I'd been utilizing.

My solution, since I am running this on Windows, is to change:

```
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {'extra/CNAME': {'path': 'CNAME'},}
```

to:

```
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {'extra\CNAME': {'path': 'CNAME'},}
                             ^ This is OS specific
```

Notice the single changed slash in the dictionary key.

Comment: This appears to be something that changed in Pelican 3.6 relative to older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Strange this behavior. The docs clearly mention that even in windows you need to use forward slashes.

From readthedocs Pelican 3.6.4 - latest release

```
STATIC_PATHS = ['images', 'extra/CNAME']
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {'extra/CNAME': {'path': 'CNAME'},}
```

Note: use forward slashes, /, even on Windows.
But this solution works.